# Bind authorative dns provides non authorative answers

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, bind

I have setup a DNS which handles 2 domains:

The first domain has an external and internal view with internal and external ip addresses and the second domain has also internal and external views but host files are with CNAMEs pointing to the records of the first domain.

My problem is that when i query for the first domain i get authorative answers. When i query a hostname in the 2nd domain i get non authorative answers and i dont know why. My configuration looks like this:

```
@ IN SOA  ns.domaina.com. domaina.com. {....
```

for the secondary domain i have:

```
@ IN SOA  ns.domaina.com. domainb.com. {....
```

my zone files  look like this:

```
zone "domaina.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/named/db.domaina.com.hosts";
    notify yes;

};

zone "subfire.net" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/named/db.domainb.com.hosts";
    notify yes;

};
```

Am i missing something ?

Comment: is `subfire.net` in the zone definitions in your question a missed obfuscation or is that deliberate? Using unaltered configs in questions means that we don't have to worry about whether you've made a typo when obfuscating things.

Comment: Is there anything in the Bind log files?

Comment: consider it as domainb :) no errors in log files at all

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without specifics to reproduce. For all we know the record you are requesting is returning a DNS referral due to presence of a `NS` record. Referrals are not considered authoritative and will never have `AA=1` set. (this is just one example)

Comment: what specifics do you need. i will do my best to provide

Comment: We need the exact queries that you are comparing. (one that has the `AA` flag present, and one that does not)

Comment: instruct me how to perform these queries

Comment: when query an entry in a domain that uses cname i get both the alias and the ip in a single query. Thats fine internally. i externally i want thhe client when performing a query on the specific CNAME to get the alias and then requery the alias to get the ip ie 2 queries. is this possible ?